# Dynamically converting multiple row values to columns with composite key

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot

I have a following data with 2 Unique Identifiers (ID1, ID2), and multiple values that spread across various times. I am trying to pivot it dynamically, because one combination of ID1 & ID2 do not have a fixed number of Values and Times. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
     ID1 INT
    ,ID2 INT
    ,Val INT
    ,[Time] Datetime
)

INSERT INTO @DataSource (ID1, ID2, Val, [Time])
VALUES   (1,1,10,'01/01/2021 12:00')
        ,(1,1,20,'01/01/2021 15:00')
        ,(1,2,30,'01/02/2021 17:00')
        ,(1,2,35,'01/02/2021 18:00')
        ,(2,1,40,'02/02/2021 08:00')
        ,(2,2,50,'02/02/2021 10:00')
        ,(2,2,60,'05/01/2021 11:00')

SELECT *
FROM @DataSource
```

[image]

I am trying to pivot it so it looks something like this and Value and Time are next to each other in sequence.

[image]

Comment: May we see what you've tried (as an image, not text, just to make it harder for us to use)?

Comment: To clarify: (1) your description `with 2 Unique Identifiers (ID1, ID2)` do fit your data since these are not Unique and you have multiple rows with the same ID1, ID2 which is actually the the rows that you want to group together. (2) Can you have 10000 times the same ID1, ID2 ? In this case you want to get result set with 20002 columns?!? If you know the maximum number of rows that needed to be grouped together (the rows with the same ID1, ID2) then there is no reason to use DYNAMIC PIVOTE which can help in performance

Comment: "do fit your data" => I meant "do NOT fit your data"

Comment: @RonenAriely I meant a unique combination ID1 & ID2 in the end result. The maximum amount of rows  per ID1 & ID2 combination could be no more than 100. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can group by `ROW_NUMBER` divided by `2`, this gets you every two rows in a group

```sql
SELECT 
    ID1,
    ID2,
    Val1 = MIN(CASE WHEN rn % 2 = 1 THEN Val END),
    Time1 = MIN(CASE WHEN rn % 2 = 1 THEN [Time] END), 
    Val2 = MIN(CASE WHEN rn % 2 = 0 THEN Val END),
    Time2 = MIN(CASE WHEN rn % 2 = 0 THEN [Time] END)
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID1, ID2 ORDER BY [Time])
    FROM YourTable t
) t
GROUP BY
    t.ID1,
    t.ID2,
    (t.rn - 1) / 2
```

Comment: Number of columns has to be dynamic. Thanks.